# Automator's Finder Actions: "Unable to search with Spotlight"

Tags: macos, finder, automator, spotlight, high-sierra

I created a workflow like this after asking [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421279/delete-downloads-older-than-30-days):

[image]

It should delete downloads older than 30 days, and has been working fine until today; today I updated to macOS High Sierra.

Now whenever the Application tries to run I'm getting the error

[image]

> The action "Filter Finder Items" encountered an error: "Unable to search with Spotlight"

How can I fix my workflow so that it works with this latest version of macOS?

Comment: When I tried to setup something similar, I caved in pretty fast with folder actions not working half the time and what ever... So I took the easy route and bought [Hazel](https://www.noodlesoft.com/). I also use [Path Finder](https://cocoatech.com), which has the ability to easily show hidden files. So I made a folder in downloads called `_old`, hid it with [`chflags` command](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chflags.1.html). Then I set a rule in Hazel: if `Date added` `is not` `today` → `Move` to folder `_old`.

Comment: This basically makes it so that my download folder only contains files from today and if I need to dig deeper, I can show hidden files and view the contents of `_old`. I guess you could also put the `_old` folder in the sidebar or favorites, to avoid having to show it every time. This obviously doesn't save any disk space, it just makes it easier to manage downloads. You could tell hazel to trash the files too.

Comment: @Joonas Hazel costs money for something that Automator should be able to do just fine anyway

Comment: That is true. I didn't say it was a necessity, I said it was the easy route.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I'd use the `find` _command_ in a new **Automator** _workflow_... add a **Run Shell Script** _action_ (settings Shell: /bin/bash _and_ Pass input: to stdin), replace the default `cat` with `find "$HOME/Downloads" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30d -iname '*.*'`, add a **Move Finder Items to Trash** _action_, save as an application. This does not traverse subdirectories, so as to avoid something Safari is downloading at the time it's run, as it uses a `.download` bundle which is a directory. Continued in next comment...

Comment: You could devise a more complex `find` _command_ and or _workflow_, however this is it's better then a nonfunctioning _workflow_.

Comment: @user3439894 do you want to add that as an answer? It looks like it may currently be the only way. I'll add it as an answer in a couple days if you don't want to do it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a (temporary) workaround, I'd use the `find` *command*.

In a new **Automator** *workflow*, add the following *actions*:

- **Run Shell Script**

  - Settings - **Shell:** `/bin/bash` *and* **Pass input:** `to stdin`
  - Replace the default `cat` with:

    ```
    find "$HOME/Downloads" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30d -iname '*.*'
    ```
- **Move Finder Items to Trash**
- Save the *workflow* as an *application*.

**Note:** As coded, this only deletes *files* at the directory level of ~/Downloads. It does not traverse subdirectories, so as to avoid deleting something Safari is downloading at the time it's run, as it uses a .download *bundle* which is a *directory*. You could devise a more complex `find` *command* and or *workflow*, however this, as is, is better then your current nonfunctioning workflow.

Answer (score 3):

I think I just figured out the problem and it is laughably stupid.

When filtering by extension, you mustn't include the "." in the filter criteria.

So, in your case, filter by IS NOT: "download" instead of ".download"

I love Automator, but sometimes it is hard to follow its logic.

Comment: are you on macOS High Sierra 10.13.3?

Comment: and you've tested this?

Comment: because the error doesn't sound like an error in file extension, e.g. when searching in Finder for the extension `.download` it doesn't error it just returns no results or w/e. The error in the question is more like something is just wrong with spotlight

Comment: Yes, I'm on 10.13.3 and I've tested this.

Not sure why it calls the error "Unable to search with Spotlight," as that really makes no sense, but I've repeatedly tested this and every time I filter by extension in Automator, it is the same. Include the "." and you get this same error, omit the "." and it processes the files absolutely fine.

Finder without an error, as you say, this seems to be an Automator issue only.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try it? Did it solve your issue as well?