# The action “Find Finder Items” encountered an error: “Unable to search with Spotlight.”

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, spotlight, search

EDIT: Ok I give up using Automator actions, probably it has something to do with my external drive being ExFat not indexed or something. If anyone has an AppleScript code or whatever workaround to replace *Find Finder Items* it would be nice.

---

This message does not produce any decent results on Google. I am just trying to search for folders/files from the selected folder, where the Service (Quick Action) is being executed. For some reason, I am getting this error.

[image]

The action is really simple, search for a name inside an external drive.

[image]

I know for a fact that "Pasta" is defined because of the results or early steps.

[image]

And I know for a fact that the folder exists.

[image]

This is the setup.

[image]

So, what the hell? Everything is enabled at Security/Accessibility, I've tried to enable File Sharing for the volume, creating pauses... And the worst part is that it worked the first time. Yes, I have restarted everything time and again. I am running out of ideas. Thanks for your time.

This is my system by the way, and this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300886/automators-finder-actions-unable-to-search-with-spotlight) is not an actual answer, but a workaround for another issue. I would like to understand what is really happening, before going after Applescripts.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it was the ExFat formatting. It took me a while to backup everything and format the disk. But usually, I regret spending a lot of time to find a workaround. Just do it. It will work either with NTFS or APFS Volume. Not sure why ExFat wouldn't work tho...